# How to trigger C# method using SQL Server Service Broker from stored procedure without using SqlDependency?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to call a C# method when I insert a new record into a table and insert xml into service broker queue from the stored procedure. I am able to perform it by using `SqlDependency`, but I don't need this - I want to perform it using the stored procedure.

You can see my code using the `SqlDependecy`. But I want another way to call C# method from a stored procedure using SQL Server Service Broker (not DB to DB).

```
public void Notification()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var queryString = "SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[Message]";

        using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            // Starting the listener infrastructure...
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, "queueName");
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, "queueName");

            var oDependency = new SqlDependency(oCommand);
            oDependency.OnChange += OnNotificationChange;

            // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
            oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}

private void ChangeNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification Info: " + e.Info);
    //Re-register the SqlDependency. 
    //var oDependency = new SqlDependency();
    //oDependency.OnChange -= OnNotificationChange;
    RegisterForNotification();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're having trouble with. There are plenty of resources that explain how Service Broker works, and it's too much to explain in an answer. At the client end, all you need is a `RECEIVE` statement, once you've set up queues and conversations.

Comment: SqlDependency is just a thin veneer that uses Service Broker anyway. You seem to be setting out, specifically, to re-invent that particular wheel.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the way `SqlDependency` uses Service Broker (focused on transient connections) does make this a wheel that can be quite worthwhile to reinvent. In particular, a regular Service Broker conversation works even when there are no applications around to pick up messages at any particular moment; `SqlDependency` does not (because it wasn't designed to do that; in fact, it's specifically designed to do the opposite).